# How i copy RGB888Pixel image to RGB byte-stream array?

Tags: opencv, openni

I have 2 pieces of this code:

```
openni::RGB888Pixel* buffer = (openni::RGB888Pixel*)frame.getData();
```

...

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<CPPImage> Image;
Image rgb;
rgb=Image(new CPPImage(640,480,3));
```

...

```
byte* dst=rgb->get_row(0);
```

I want to copy the data from buffer to dest. dest is RGB Image.
How I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The data in the openni RGB888Pixel array can be interpreted as a uchar 1 dimension array of size height*width*3. Each uchar of this array will tell you the red, green or blue value of each pixel. The order would be by rows and rgb, so the array will be something like

```
r_1,g_1,b_1,r_2,g_2,b2.....
```

Having this in mind, you can copy the data to any image container that have the data organized in the same way (i.e. opencv Mat) using memcpy. Here is a snippet of [my code](https://github.com/cvlabbonn/tools_openni2) using opencv images as example

```
cv::Mat cv_image;
const openni::RGB888Pixel* imageBuffer = (const openni::RGB888Pixel*)colorFrame.getData();
cv_image.create(colorFrame.getHeight(), colorFrame.getWidth(), CV_8UC3);
memcpy( cv_image.data, imageBuffer,3*colorFrame.getHeight()*colorFrame.getWidth()*sizeof(uint8_t) );
```

For other image containers you have to be sure that the order in the array is the correct one. If it is not the same order just do a for in the openni data and copy it in the correct order... (though this can be slower)

Comment: I use your code, and visual studio say that it have read violation.

Comment: you mean the snippet here? that is weird, I have used this snippet in a recent program but instead of openni with kinnect sdk and it worked. Which line is giving you the reading violation? are you sure you have valid data in the buffer?

Comment: I have issue more difficult with this. can you help me to solve it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908539/change-resolution-on-openni2-not-working

Comment: Thank you so much!