# Change resolution on openni2 not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, openni

I want to read depth frame at 640x480.

I am using windows 8.1 64bit, openni2 32bit, kinect:PSMP05000,PSCM04900(PrimeSense)

I take code reference from here:

[cannot set VGA resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538715/prime-sense-on-the-mac-cannot-set-vga-resolution)

[Simple Read](https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2/tree/master/Samples/SimpleRead)

Combined to this code:

[main.cpp](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3363579/main.cpp)

[OniSampleUtilities.h](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3363579/OniSampleUtilities.h)

[SimpleRead.vcxproj](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3363579/SimpleRead.vcxproj)

should be compiled if you install openni2 32bit from here:

[OpeniNI 2](http://structure.io/openni)

```
#include "iostream"
#include "OpenNI.h"
#include "OniSampleUtilities.h" 

#define SAMPLE_READ_WAIT_TIMEOUT 2000 //2000ms

using namespace openni;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Status rc = OpenNI::initialize();
    if (rc != STATUS_OK)
    {
        cout << "Initialize failed:" << endl << OpenNI::getExtendedError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Device device;
    rc = device.open(ANY_DEVICE);
    if (rc != STATUS_OK)
    {
        cout << "Couldn't open device" << endl << OpenNI::getExtendedError() << endl;
        return 2;
    }

    VideoStream depth;

    if (device.getSensorInfo(SENSOR_DEPTH) != NULL)
    {
        rc = depth.create(device, SENSOR_DEPTH);
        if (rc != STATUS_OK)
        {
            cout << "Couldn't create depth stream" << endl << OpenNI::getExtendedError() << endl;
            return 3;
        }
    }

    rc = depth.start();
    if (rc != STATUS_OK)
    {
        cout << "Couldn't start the depth stream" << endl << OpenNI::getExtendedError() << endl;
        return 4;
    }

    VideoFrameRef frame;

    // set resolution
    // depth modes
    cout << "Depth modes" << endl;
    const openni::SensorInfo* sinfo = device.getSensorInfo(openni::SENSOR_DEPTH); // select index=4 640x480, 30 fps, 1mm
    const openni::Array< openni::VideoMode>& modesDepth = sinfo->getSupportedVideoModes();
    for (int i = 0; i<modesDepth.getSize(); i++) {
        printf("%i: %ix%i, %i fps, %i format\n", i, modesDepth[i].getResolutionX(), modesDepth[i].getResolutionY(),
            modesDepth[i].getFps(), modesDepth[i].getPixelFormat()); //PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_1_MM = 100, PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_100_UM
    }
    rc = depth.setVideoMode(modesDepth[0]);
    if (openni::STATUS_OK != rc)
    {
        cout << "error: depth fromat not supprted..." << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    while (!wasKeyboardHit())
    {
        int changedStreamDummy;
        VideoStream* pStream = &depth;
        rc = OpenNI::waitForAnyStream(&pStream, 1, &changedStreamDummy, SAMPLE_READ_WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        if (rc != STATUS_OK)
        {
            cout << "Wait failed! (timeout is " << SAMPLE_READ_WAIT_TIMEOUT << " ms)" << endl << OpenNI::getExtendedError() << endl;
            continue;
        }

        rc = depth.readFrame(&frame);
        if (rc != STATUS_OK)
        {
            cout << "Read failed!" << endl << OpenNI::getExtendedError() << endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (frame.getVideoMode().getPixelFormat() != PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_1_MM && frame.getVideoMode().getPixelFormat() != PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_100_UM)
        {
            cout << "Unexpected frame format" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        DepthPixel* pDepth = (DepthPixel*)frame.getData();

        int middleIndex = (frame.getHeight()+1)*frame.getWidth()/2;

        printf("[%08llu] %8d\n", (long long)frame.getTimestamp(), pDepth[middleIndex]);
    }

    depth.stop();
    depth.destroy();
    device.close();
    OpenNI::shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

There is 6 mode of operation:

```
0: 320x240, 30 fps, 100 format
1: 320x240, 30 fps, 101 format
2: 320x240, 60 fps, 100 format
3: 320x240, 60 fps, 101 format
4: 640x480, 30 fps, 100 format
5: 640x480, 30 fps, 101 format
```

It can read only from modes=0-3.

At mode 4,5 i get timeout. 

How i can read depth frame at 640x480?

Thanks for the help,

Tal.

====================================================

new information:

I use also this line, and i get the same results:

```
const openni::SensorInfo* sinfo = &(depth.getSensorInfo());
```

This line never execute at any mode:

```
cout << "error: depth fromat not supprted..." << endl;
```

At mode 4,5 I always get this line execute:

```
cout << "Wait failed! (timeout is " << SAMPLE_READ_WAIT_TIMEOUT << " ms)" << endl << OpenNI::getExtendedError() << endl;
```

I think maybe it a bug at openni2. 

At openni1, I can read depth image at 640x480, in the same computer,os and device.

Comment: instead of `device.getSensorInfo(openni::SENSOR_DEPTH);`
try `depth.getSensorInfo();` and see modesDepth datas again.

Comment: it the same :(. say exactly same modes. when i use modes 4,5. cannot read.
I use this line:
const openni::SensorInfo* sinfo = &(depth.getSensorInfo());

Comment: try this :
`openni::VideoMode depth_videoMode  = depth.getVideoMode();
depth_videoMode.setResolution(width, height);
depth_videoMode.setFps(fps);
depth.setVideoMode(depth_videoMode);`
and fill width, height, fps with suitable values

Comment: I try this before, and the same result. :-\

Comment: if this line is not execute, your program should work :-?
`cout << "error: depth fromat not supprted..." << endl;`

Comment: this line not execute. i get status ok. the program running, and i get always this line:
cout << "Wait failed! (timeout is " << SAMPLE_READ_WAIT_TIMEOUT << " ms)" << endl << OpenNI::getExtendedError() << endl;

Comment: which kinect driver are you using? are you using a kinect or a primesense camera?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am wrong, but I am almost sure that the problem is the order that you are doing it.

I think you should change it `before depth.start()` and after `depth.create(device, SENSOR_DEPTH)`

If I remember correctly, once it has started you may bot change the resolution of the stream.

So it should be something like this

```
...

if (device.getSensorInfo(SENSOR_DEPTH) != NULL)
{
    rc = depth.create(device, SENSOR_DEPTH);
    if (rc != STATUS_OK)
    {
        cout << "Couldn't create depth stream" << endl << OpenNI::getExtendedError() << endl;
        return 3;
    }
}

// set resolution
// depth modes
cout << "Depth modes" << endl;
const openni::SensorInfo* sinfo = device.getSensorInfo(openni::SENSOR_DEPTH);
const openni::Array< openni::VideoMode>& modesDepth = sinfo->getSupportedVideoModes();
rc = depth.setVideoMode(modesDepth[0]);
if (openni::STATUS_OK != rc)
{
    cout << "error: depth fromat not supprted..." << endl;
}

rc = depth.start();
if (rc != STATUS_OK)
{
    cout << "Couldn't start the depth stream" << endl << OpenNI::getExtendedError() << endl;
    return 4;
}

VideoFrameRef frame;



...
```

I hope that this helps you, if not, please add a comment. I have a similar code working in the git repository I show you the other day, tested with a PrimeSense carmine camera.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Asus Xtion PRO in a USB 3.0 port, OpenNI2, Windows 8.1), it seems there are something wrong with OpenNI2 (or its driver) that prevents me from changing the resolution in the code. NiViewer simple hangs or has frame rates drop significantly if the color resolution is set to 640x480.

However, on Windows, I managed to change the resolution by changing the settings in PS1080.ini in OpenNI2/Tools/OpenNI2/Drivers folder. In the ini file, for Asus, make sure

UsbInterface = 2

is enabled. By default it's zero. Then set Resolution = 1 for the depth and image sections.

My Asus Xtion firmware is v5.8.22.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the method @api55 mentioned and it works. The code and result are in the following.

**But there is a problem** when I make the similar change to the OpenNI sample code "SampleViewer" so that I can change the resolution free. When I set the resolution to 320*240 all is well. However, when I change it to 640*480, although the program still read frames in (at a apparently slower rate), the program display just get stuck.

2015-12-27 15:15:32

Then I test the aforementioned sample viewer with **a kinect 1.0 depth camera**. Since the color camera has a resolution no less than 640*480, I cannot experiment the resolution of 320*240. But the program works well with kinect 1.0 at a resolution of 640*480. In conclusion, I think that there must be some problem with the ASUS Xtion camera.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <OpenNI.h>
#include "OniSampleUtilities.h" 

#pragma comment(lib, "OpenNI2")

#define SAMPLE_READ_WAIT_TIMEOUT 2000 //2000ms

using namespace openni;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Status rc = OpenNI::initialize();
    if (rc != STATUS_OK)
    {
        printf("Initialize failed:\n%s\n", OpenNI::getExtendedError());
        return 1;
    }

    Device device;

    openni::Array<openni::DeviceInfo> deviceInfoList;
    OpenNI::enumerateDevices(&deviceInfoList);

    for (int i = 0; i < deviceInfoList.getSize(); i++)
    {
        printf("%d: Uri: %s\n"
            "Vendor: %s\n"
            "Name: %s\n", i, deviceInfoList[i].getUri(), deviceInfoList[i].getVendor(), deviceInfoList[i].getName());
    }

    rc = device.open(deviceInfoList[0].getUri());
    if (rc != STATUS_OK)
    {
        printf("Counldn't open device\n%s\n", OpenNI::getExtendedError());
        return 2;
    }

    VideoStream depth;

    // set resolution
    // depth modes
    printf("\nDepth modes\n");
    const openni::SensorInfo* sinfo = device.getSensorInfo(openni::SENSOR_DEPTH); // select index=4 640x480, 30 fps, 1mm
    if (sinfo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't get device info\n%s\n", OpenNI::getExtendedError());
        return 3;
    }

    rc = depth.create(device, SENSOR_DEPTH);
    if (rc != STATUS_OK)
    {
        printf("Couldn't create depth stream\n%s\n", OpenNI::getExtendedError());
        return 4;
    }


    const openni::Array< openni::VideoMode>& modesDepth = sinfo->getSupportedVideoModes();
    vector<int> item;
    for (int i = 0; i < modesDepth.getSize(); i++) {
        printf("%i: %ix%i, %i fps, %i format\n", i, modesDepth[i].getResolutionX(), modesDepth[i].getResolutionY(),
            modesDepth[i].getFps(), modesDepth[i].getPixelFormat()); //PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_1_MM = 100, PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_100_UM
        if (modesDepth[i].getResolutionX() == 640 && modesDepth[i].getResolutionY() == 480)
            item.push_back(i);
    }

    int item_idx = item[0];
    printf("Choose mode %d\nWidth: %d, Height: %d\n", item_idx, modesDepth[item_idx].getResolutionX(), modesDepth[item_idx].getResolutionY());

    rc = depth.setVideoMode(modesDepth[item_idx]);
    if (rc != STATUS_OK)
    {
        printf("error: depth format not supported...\n");
        return 5;
    }

    rc = depth.start();
    if (rc != STATUS_OK)
    {
        printf("Couldn't start the depth stream\n%s\n", OpenNI::getExtendedError());
        return 6;
    }

    VideoFrameRef frame;

    printf("\nCurrent resolution:\n");
    printf("Width: %d  Height: %d\n", depth.getVideoMode().getResolutionX(), depth.getVideoMode().getResolutionY());


    system("pause");
    while (!wasKeyboardHit())
    {
        int changedStreamDummy;
        VideoStream* pStream = &depth;
        rc = OpenNI::waitForAnyStream(&pStream, 1, &changedStreamDummy, SAMPLE_READ_WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        if (rc != STATUS_OK)
        {
            printf("Wait failed! (timeout is \" %d \" ms)\n%s\n", SAMPLE_READ_WAIT_TIMEOUT, OpenNI::getExtendedError());
            continue;
        }

        rc = depth.readFrame(&frame);
        if (rc != STATUS_OK)
        {
            printf("Read failed!\n%s\n", OpenNI::getExtendedError());
            continue;
        }

        if (frame.getVideoMode().getPixelFormat() != PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_1_MM && frame.getVideoMode().getPixelFormat() != PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_100_UM)
        {
            printf("Unexpected frame format\n");
            continue;
        }

        DepthPixel* pDepth = (DepthPixel*)frame.getData();

        int middleIndex = (frame.getHeight() + 1)*frame.getWidth() / 2;

        printf("[%08llu] %8d\n", (long long)frame.getTimestamp(), pDepth[middleIndex]);
        printf("Width: %d  Height: %d\n", frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
    }

    depth.stop();
    depth.destroy();
    device.close();
    OpenNI::shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Here is the result:]

Comment: I have the same problem. Don't think it's the problem of asus xtion, because  NiViewer works well with higher resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but now solved it by referencing NiViewer example in OpenNI2. Apparently after you start the stream, either depth or color, you have to stop it to change the resolution and then start

```
const openni::SensorInfo* sinfo = device.getSensorInfo(openni::SENSOR_DEPTH);
const openni::Array< openni::VideoMode>& modesDepth = sinfo->getSupportedVideoModes();
depth.stop();
rc = depth.setVideoMode(modesDepth[4]);
depth.start();
```

I confirmed that this works on Asus Xtion on OpenNI2.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Final conclusion:**

Actually, it is Xtion's problem **itself** (maybe related to hardware).

If you want just one of depth or color to be 640*480, and the other to be 320*240, it'll work. I can post my code if you want.

**Details**

Some of the answers above made a mistake: even the NiViewer.exe itself doesn't allow a depth 640*480 and color 640*480 at the same time.

**Note:** don't be misled by the visualization of NiViewer.exe, the video stream displayed is large but actually it does not mean 640*480. Actually it is initialsed with

- depth: 320*240
- color: 320*240

When you set either of the mode to 640*480, it is still works, which is

- depth: 640*480
- color: 320*240

or

- depth: 320*240
- color: 640*480

But when you want both of them to be the highest resolution:

- depth: 640*480
- color: 640*480

The viewer program starts encountering acute frame drop in the depth mode (in my case), but since the viewer retrieves the depth frame in an un-block way (the default code is written in a block way), you still see the color updates normally, while the depth updates every two seconds or even more.

**To conclude**

You could only set either of depth or color to be 640*480, and the other to be 320*240.